# Cannot access session array from view in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, ruby-on-rails-3.1, session-variables

So this one has me stumped; hopefully a kind soul can help me out. As part of logic to display certain buttons for users who have performed an action, I store the id of the object they manipulated in a session array called "prayed_for". *(The unique part of this problem is that it deals with sessions and not an array persisted in a database.)* In the show action of my controller, I evaluate whether of not the current id of the entry being requested is present in the session array "prayed_for". I assign this boolean value to the session variable `@already_prayed_for`. Below is the logic for that:

```
@already_prayed_for = (session[:prayed_for] ||= []).include? params[:id]
```

But here's the problem: I cannot evaluate this in my partial. For example if I attempt to evaluate the following (in HAML), where "entry" is a variable representing the entry at hand and "id" is it's id, which should be stored in the session "prayed_for" variable, it will always evaluate to `false`:

```
-if (session[:prayed_for] ||= []).include? entry.id
```

I've come to the conclusion that I may be evaluating something wrong in my partial when evaluating whether or not an id is present in a session array. Additionally this same concept worked perfectly in a controller action *(but I can't use that solution this time around, it has to be evaluated in the partial)* but it also failed in the `ApplicationHelper`. Any help in resolving this problem is much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
Here's the code where I set the session in another action:

```
if @entry.save
  (session[:prayed_for] ||= []) << params[:id]
end
```

Comment: Can you also post the line(s) of code where you set the session?

Comment: Please see my update on the question for those lines of code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params[:id]` may be a String, while `entry.id` is a Fixnum. Verify that the objects you're comparing (via `include?`) are of the same type.

You might want to make a helper out of the logic you're using, for example:

```
def already_prayed_for?(entry_id)
  (session[:prayed_for] ||= []).include? entry_id.to_i
end
```

Comment: I understand the problem now! Thank you! One quick question: I'm using Mongoid an don't have access to `.to_i`. Is there any other method I could use that does the same thing?

Comment: I found that I had to use `.to_s` in the helper you provided to make everything work with the parameters string representations. Thank you so much for your help!